# Answer wrongly deleted

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-answers

So I had this very same question and couldn't find the answer anywhere.
I created the formula to answer it and the answer simply got deleted by a moderator because of some weird politics.

Credits? F* it, right?

[Predict number of points returned mid-point circle algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200843/predict-number-of-points-returned-mid-point-circle-algortihm/)

Comment: Nothing to do with "politics". Your post, that you posted as an "answer" was not answering the question - you were chiming in with something that should have been a comment on the question. Now, I understand that you do not have the reputation to comment on posts that are not yours, but the action was right - it was not an answer and should have been deleted.

Comment: Is yours the answer that Jean-Yves is referring to?

Comment: Looking at it in context - Jves got the accept for the same (slightly reformatted answer) that Dangufaer gave... And it looks like an answer to me....

Comment: Jean-Yves is also the asker, so it's a self-accept.

Comment: No weird politics, just a mistake it seems.

Comment: For future questions on Meta, it's probably a good idea not to make assumptions (that the deletion was "politics", for instance) or point fingers. Just ask why it was deleted (you were in the right, after all!)

Comment: Accusations, swearing, meh. Could have just asked what happened instead.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the FAQ says that answers on old or inactive questions are deleted. And this is what I was referring to. I expressed myself starting with "I was looking for the same answer" because it sounded like he already had an answer that was fitting his needs, but I wanted to put it there for future references, because I couldn't find the real answer anywhere. And, yes, I was accusing an _organization_ and I didn't named anyone.

Answer (score 5):

Your answer:

> I have been looking for the same answer, I took your formula as a basis and got this:
>
> floor((sqrt(2)*(radius-1)+4)/2)*8
>
> And it's working just fine :)

looked like it was just repeating an answer and comment from November 2011 and thanking the poster.  On closer scrutiny, it does look like you reworked the formula a bit, so I think your answer should stand.  It's undeleted now.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing it's because of the wording you used:

> I have been looking for the same answer...

That's a red flag right there. People post "answers" all the time that are really just something like "I have this problem too, I tried this `code(x){return y;}` Can someone help?"

I can't comment on the correctness or validity of the answer itself, but I would guess this might be the reason.

It's not really your fault, but next time be more careful with the way you present answers.